# SIMPLE-READER-ERROR , illegal sharp macro character, Subcharacter #\< not defined for dispatch char #\#

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp, hashtable, dispatch

In chapter 4 of the book, Successful Lisp, by David B. Lamkins,
there is a simple application to keep track of bank checks.

https://dept-info.labri.fr/~strandh/Teaching/MTP/Common/David-Lamkins/chapter04.html

At the end, we write a macro that will save and restore functions.
The problem occurs when I execute the reader function and the value to read is the hash table.

The macro to save and restore functions is:

```
(defmacro def-i/o (writer-name reader-name (&rest vars))
  (let ((file-name (gensym))
        (var (gensym))
        (stream (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,writer-name (,file-name)
         (with-open-file (,stream ,file-name
                                  :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
           (dolist (,var (list ,@vars))
             (declare (special ,@vars))
             (print ,var ,stream))))
       (defun ,reader-name (,file-name)
         (with-open-file (,stream ,file-name
                                  :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error)
           (dolist (,var ',vars)
             (set ,var (read ,stream)))))
       t)))
```

Here is my hash table and what is going on:

```
    (defvar *payees* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))

    (check-check 100.00 "Acme" "Rocket booster T-1000")

    CL-USER> *payees*
    #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 0 {25520F91}>

    CL-USER> (check-check 100.00 "Acme" "T-1000 rocket booster")
    #S(CHECK
    :NUMBER 100
    :DATE "2020-4-1"
    :AMOUNT 100.0
    :PAID "Acme"
    :MEMO "T-1000 rocket booster")
    CL-USER> (def-i/o save-checks charge-checks (*payees*))
    T
    CL-USER> (save-checks "/home/checks.dat")
    NIL
    CL-USER> (makunbound '*payees*)
    *PAYEES*

    CL-USER> (load-checks "/home/checks.dat")
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR "illegal sharp macro character: ~S" {258A8541}>.
```

In Lispworks, the error message is:

```
Error: subcharacter #\< not defined for dispatch char #\#.
```

To simplify, I get the same error if I execute:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *payees* (make-hash-table :test #'equal)) 
*PAYEES*
CL-USER> (with-open-file (in "/home/checks.dat"
                 :direction :input)
       (set *payees* (read in)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR "illegal sharp macro character: ~S" {23E83B91}>.
```

Can someone explain to me where the problem is coming from, and what I need to fix in my code for this to work.
Thank you in advance for the explanations you can give me and the help you can give me.

Comment: Using the function `SET`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values which cannot be read back are printed with `#<`, see [Sharpsign Less-Than-Sign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dht.htm). Common Lisp does not define how hash-tables should be printed readably (there is no reader syntax for hash tables):

```
* (make-hash-table)
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL :COUNT 0 {1006556E53}>
```

The example in the book is only suitable to be used with the *bank* example that was previously shown, and is not intended to be a general-purpose serialization mechanism.

There are many ways to print a hash-table and read them back, depending on your needs, but there is no default representation. See [*cl-store*](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-store/) for a library that store arbitrary objects.

### Custom `dump` function

Let's write a form that evaluate to an equivalent hash-table; let's define a generic function named `dump`, and a default method that simply returns the object as-is:

```
(defgeneric dump (object)
  (:method (object) object))
```

Given a hash-table, we can serialize it as a *plist* (sequence of key/value elements in a list), while also calling `dump` on keys and values, in case our hash-tables contain hash-tables:

```
(defun hash-table-plist-dump (hash &aux plist)
  (with-hash-table-iterator (next hash)
    (loop
       (multiple-value-bind (some key value) (next)
         (unless some
           (return plist))
         (push (dump value) plist)
         (push (dump key) plist)))))
```

Instead of reinventing the wheel, we could also have used `hash-table-plist` from the [*alexandria*](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) system.

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
(defun hash-table-plist-dump (hash)
  (mapcar #'dump (alexandria:hash-table-plist hash)))
```

Then, we can specialize `dump` for hash-tables:

```
(defmethod dump ((hash hash-table))
  (loop
     for (initarg accessor) 
     in '((:test hash-table-test)
          (:size hash-table-size)
          (:rehash-size hash-table-rehash-size)
          (:rehash-threshold hash-table-rehash-threshold))
     collect initarg into args
     collect `(quote ,(funcall accessor hash)) into args
     finally (return
               (alexandria:with-gensyms (h k v)
                 `(loop
                     :with ,h := (make-hash-table ,@args)
                     :for (,k ,v)
                     :on (list ,@(hash-table-plist-dump hash))
                     :by #'cddr
                     :do (setf (gethash ,k ,h) ,v)
                     :finally (return ,h))))))
```

The first part of the loop computes all the hash-table properties, like the kind of hash function to use or the rehash-size, and builds `args`, the argument list for a call to `make-hash-table` with the same values.

In the `finally` clause, we build a `loop` expression (see backquotes) that first allocates the hash-table, then populates it according to the current values of the hash, and finally return the new hash. Note that the generated code does not depend on *alexandria*, it could be read back from another Lisp system that does not have this dependency.

### Example

```
CL-USER> (alexandria:plist-hash-table '("abc" 0 "def" 1 "ghi" 2 "jkl" 3)
                 :test #'equal)

#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 4 {100C91F8C3}>
```

Dump it:

```
CL-USER> (dump *)
(LOOP :WITH #:H603 := (MAKE-HASH-TABLE :TEST 'EQUAL :SIZE '14 :REHASH-SIZE '1.5
                                       :REHASH-THRESHOLD '1.0)
      :FOR (#:K604 #:V605) :ON (LIST "jkl" 3 "ghi" 2 "def" 1 "abc"
                                     0) :BY #'CDDR
      :DO (SETF (GETHASH #:K604 #:H603) #:V605)
      :FINALLY (RETURN #:H603))
```

The generated data is also valid Lisp code, evaluate it:

```
CL-USER> (eval *)
#<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQUAL :COUNT 4 {100CD5CE93}>
```

The resulting hash is `equalp` to the original one:

```
CL-USER> (equalp * ***)
T
```